# How to delete text before a dot (.)

Tags: autohotkey

I have no idea how to write a script to make it work. However, I do know autohotkey is a strong program which can help me save time.

Please help me write a script that can delete the middle names which are usually abbreviated with a dot after it, such as:

-> Stephen M. Merkel

-> Wiliam J. Moran

The result I want after pressing a hotkey:

=> Stephen Merkel

=> Wiliam Moran

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thank you!!

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: This is what I saw on the internet, this script will remove all the single characters from string/clipboard. But I really don't know how to make it work: s := RegExReplace(clipboard, "\b\S\b\s+", "")

Comment: `RegExReplace(Clipboard," \w\. "," ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SendMode, Input

; -- Ctrl + . -> Delete middle name from selection

^.::
While GetKeyState("Ctrl","P")
    Sleep, 25
Clipboard := ""
Send, ^c
ClipWait, 0
If ErrorLevel
    Return
Sleep, 50
Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "([A-Z][a-z]+) [A-Z]\. ([A-Z][a-z]+)", "$1 $2")
Send, ^v
Return
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, daredevil!! May I ask one more question please? If the middle name is longer than one letter (maybe 2 or 3), how can we add to this script?

Comment: Use this line instead:

`Clipboard := RegExReplace(Clipboard, "([A-Z][a-z]+) [A-Z][a-z]{0,2}\. ([A-Z][a-z]+)", "$1 $2")`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! You saved my day :D